# C++ gstreamer - seamlessly loop a GIF file

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I have a C++ wrapper over the GStreamer library that displays various file types for my application. I'm currently implementing support for images, and while I got jpgs/pngs working without any problem, I'm having trouble with GIFs. The file is displayed properly, it's being animated although I cannot seem to find any way to loop the GIF seamlessly so it displays the same way as in the browser for example. I'm working on Linux with waylandsink. GStreamer version 1.14.4.

I tried many different ways:

1. Seeking with `gst_element_seek` or `gst_element_seek_simple` under the `GST_MESSAGE_EOS`. This hangs the display at the end and produces an infinite loop of state changes (from PAUSED->PLAYING followed by `GST_MESSAGE_EOS`)
2. Setting the pipeline state to `NULL` and then to `PLAYING` under `GST_MESSAGE_EOS`. This works, but produces a black gap between the reloads, which doesn't satisfy me since I want the gif to loop seamlessly.
3. Seeking to the first segment when pipeline enters the `PLAYING` state, and then seeking back under `GST_MESSAGE_SEGMENT_DONE`. This jumps straight to EOS at the first frame.

Here is how I'm building the pipeline:

```cpp
m_pipeline = gst_parse_launch("playbin uri=file:///home/user/test.gif video-sink=waylandsink");
```

Here's my loop:

```cpp
  m_ret = gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (m_ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref(m_pipeline);
    exit(0);
  }
  m_bus = gst_element_get_bus(m_pipeline);

  m_terminate = FALSE;
  GError *err;
  gchar *debug_info;
  bool seekOnce = false;
  do {
    m_msg =
          gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(m_bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, (GstMessageType)(GST_MESSAGE_EOS | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_SEGMENT_DONE));
    /* Parse message */
    if (m_msg != NULL) {

      switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(m_msg)) {
      case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        gst_message_parse_error(m_msg, &err, &debug_info);
        g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n",
                   GST_OBJECT_NAME(m_msg->src), err->message);
        g_printerr("Debugging information: %s\n",
                   debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
        g_clear_error(&err);
        g_free(debug_info);
        m_terminate = TRUE;
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
          g_print("Received EOS!\n");
          // This produces no errors but loops PAUSED->PLAYING->EOS
          if(gst_element_seek(m_pipeline, 1.0, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, 0, GST_SEEK_TYPE_NONE, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE)) {
                  g_print("SEEK FAILED!\n");
          }

        // this loops, but since it's re-starting the entire pipeline the loop is not seamless
        //gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
        //gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
        if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC(m_msg) == GST_OBJECT(m_pipeline)) {
            GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
          gst_message_parse_state_changed(m_msg, &old_state, &new_state,
                                          &pending_state);
          g_print("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s\n",
                  gst_element_state_get_name(old_state),
                  gst_element_state_get_name(new_state));

          if(new_state == GstState::GST_STATE_PLAYING) {
              // this jumps straight to EOS on the first frame, GST_MESSAGE_SEGMENT_DONE is not received at all
              if(!seekOnce)
                    //  gst_element_seek_simple(m_pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, (GstSeekFlags)(GST_SEEK_FLAG_SEGMENT | GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH), 0);
                  seekOnce = true;

              }
          }
        }
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_SEGMENT_DONE:
          //gst_element_seek_simple(m_pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_SEGMENT, 0);
          break;
      default:
        /* We should not reach here */
        g_printerr("Unexpected message received.\n");
        break;
      }
      gst_message_unref(m_msg);
    }

  } while (!m_terminate);
```

How can I make the loop seamless, like it should be with looping GIFs?